# Import firebase DB values into googlesheet

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets-api

I have a project which uses firebase database to store data, the structure of my firebase DB table is as follows:

```
table_name
   | abc12345677890xxxxxxxxx
       | key_namea: 45852
       | key_nameb: "string characters"
       | key_namec: 45852
       | key_named: "string characters"
       | key_named: "string characters"
       | secondleveldeep
          | key_name: value
          | key_name: value
```

I looked into googlesheet api and came up with a function thats meant to get the data but every time i run into the following error

"Error: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 272, file "Code", project"

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,5000,1); // unclear about this
  var data = getFirebaseBase('table_name');
  Logger.log(data);
  range.setValues(JSON.parse(data));  
}

function getFirebaseBase (data) {
  var firebaseUrl  = 'https:xxx.firebaseio.com';
  var secret = 'abcXXXX...';
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
  var result = base.getData(data);
  return result;
}
```

Has anyone successfully imported data from firebase into googlesheet (NOT INTERESTED IN THE REVERSE), if so please could you shed some light what i'm missing or not doing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your spreadsheet in real time with every change to your database using a [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

It's a somewhat involved process to set up, but you can see this in action in a [tweet with an animated GIF](https://twitter.com/CodingDoug/status/940022568089554944).

Click through to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/ffc4f050cc489a0280eb7f4cbe36af07) for instructions and source code.  This example is a minimal simple example, and you'll probably want to extend that to your specific use case.

You can also [go the other direction](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/44ad12f4836e79ca9fa11ba5af6955f7) if you become interested in that.